# Displaying DEM raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, dem

Using Raster>Analysis>DEM to display hillshade produces the message "gdaldem.exe had stopped working" so I asked the community. I'm new to QGIS, and I now realise after a little experimentation that I should have used Raster>Terrain Analysis>Hillshade which now works OK - just in case another newbie has encountered the same problem. Why the former action should crash gdaldem.exe remains a slight concern though.

Comment: Maybe because to display a hillshade you have to use Raster>Terrain Analysis>Hillshade and not Raster>Analysis>DEM.